# create db - prevent creation of users

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2

On SQL Server 2008R2, we have a SQL login tagged with the sysadmin server role.  Anytime a db is created, this login is automatically added as a user to the db.  Is there a switch that will prevent this from happening?

EDIT:
Based on the answer below, I am adding more background info to explain why we want to do this.

When we publish to a new database from a Visual Studio SQL project, the publishing engine wants to add a user to the database.  The username already exists as a login to the database (in the sysadmin server role -- and not much we can do about that), so the publish fails as the user gets auto-added by SQL server after the 'create database' statement.  I was hoping for a switch that would tell SQL Server to not add the user automatically.  So it seems we will have to find another solution on the VS side that tells the publishing engine to ignore the SQL DB user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a resolution to this.  Download the latest SSDT package from MS and now there are new options under the **Publishing Wizard *Advanced...*** button to exclude the publishing of logins, roles, etc.  The SSDT package I downloaded I found here...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/dn864412

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the sql-server role, I don't think so. TBH if you're contemplating keeping a sys-admin out of a db, then you've got a different problem than the one you think you have...